# How would I search my binary tree to find a target?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have been working on this code for a while with no luck. I understand that I need to pass my tree through this method, but I'm unsure of how to do that.

I think my algorithm is correct, but it keeps telling me "null" no matter what I put in. Any feedback can help, I think it keeps returning null because I don't know how to pass the tree through the method.

Below, my find2 method is supposed to use the tree created by my add2 method to find the selected node. This also includes my main method.

Here's the code:

```
public boolean add2(E item) {
    root = add2(root, item);
    return addReturn;
}

private Node<E> add2(Node<E> localRoot, E item){
    if(localRoot == null) {
        //Adding item if tree is empty...
        addReturn = true;
        return new Node<>(item);
    } else if (item.compareTo(localRoot.data) == 0) {
        //Returning item if equal to root...
        addReturn = false;
        return localRoot;
    } else if (item.compareTo(localRoot.data) < 0) {
        //Adding item to right side of tree if less than the root...
        localRoot.right = add(localRoot.right, item);
        return localRoot;
    } else {
        //Adding item to left side of tree if grater than the root...
        localRoot.left = add(localRoot.left, item);
        return localRoot;
    }
}

//wrapper method
public E find2(E target) {
    return find2(root, target);
}

//recursive method
private E find2(Node<E> localRoot, E target) {
    if(localRoot == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int compResult2 = target.compareTo(localRoot.data);

    if(compResult2 == 0) {
        return localRoot.data;
    } else if (compResult2 < 0) {
        return find2(localRoot.right, target);
    } else {
        return find2(localRoot.left, target);
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTreeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Object creation
    BinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<>();

    //Tree building...
    tree.add2(50);
    tree.add2(70);
    tree.add2(80);
    tree.add2(60);
    tree.add2(30);
    tree.add2(40);
    tree.add2(20);

    //Output tree
    System.out.println("\nThe built binary search tree:");
    System.out.println("\n" + tree.toString());

    System.out.println("\nSearch the node with data 60: " + tree.find2(60));
    System.out.println("Search the node with data 65: " + tree.find2(65));
    System.out.println("Search the node with data 20: " + tree.find2(20));
    System.out.println("Search the node with data 25: " + tree.find2(25));

}
```

}

Comment: Can you include more of your code? there is not enough of your code to definitively locate the issue.

Comment: How do you insert a node to the tree? show us the code

Comment: Can't spot the issue in find methods here as well. Might be a problem with compareTo with typeof(E), or Node class itself, more information would be needed

Comment: I added to the code, I hope that helps.

Comment: The best way to solve problems like this is to single-step the code in your debugger. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. It will save you countless hours of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to my local, change in `add2` method call to `add2` not `add`

```
        static class BinarySearchTree<Item extends Comparable> {

        Node root;
        boolean addReturn;

        class Node {
            Item data;
            Node left;
            Node right;

            public Node(Item e) {
                data = e;
            }
        }

        public boolean add2(Item item) {
            root = add2(root, item);
            return addReturn;
        }

        private Node add2(Node localRoot, Item item) {
            if (localRoot == null) {
                // Adding item if tree is empty...
                addReturn = true;
                return new Node(item);
            } else if (item.compareTo(localRoot.data) == 0) {
                // Returning item if equal to root...
                addReturn = false;
                return localRoot;
            } else if (item.compareTo(localRoot.data) < 0) {
                // Adding item to right side of tree if less than the root...
                localRoot.right = add2(localRoot.right, item);
                return localRoot;
            } else {
                // Adding item to left side of tree if grater than the root...
                localRoot.left = add2(localRoot.left, item);
                return localRoot;
            }
        }

        // wrapper method
        public Item find2(Item target) {
            return find2(root, target);
        }

        // recursive method
        private Item find2(Node localRoot, Item target) {
            if (localRoot == null) {
                return null;
            }
            int compResult2 = target.compareTo(localRoot.data);
            if (compResult2 == 0) {
                return localRoot.data;
            } else if (compResult2 < 0) {
                return find2(localRoot.right, target);
            } else {
                return find2(localRoot.left, target);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Object creation
        BinarySearchTree<Integer> tree = new BinarySearchTree<>();

        // Tree building...
        tree.add2(50);
        tree.add2(70);
        tree.add2(80);
        tree.add2(60);
        tree.add2(30);
        tree.add2(40);
        tree.add2(20);

        // Output tree
        System.out.println("\nThe built binary search tree:");
        System.out.println("\n" + tree.toString());

        System.out.println("\nSearch the node with data 60: " + tree.find2(60));
        System.out.println("Search the node with data 65: " + tree.find2(65));
        System.out.println("Search the node with data 20: " + tree.find2(20));
        System.out.println("Search the node with data 25: " + tree.find2(25));

    }
```

, And gives me the output:

```
Search the node with data 60: 60
Search the node with data 65: null
Search the node with data 20: 20
Search the node with data 25: null
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it while keeping the data type of the find2 method generic (ie. type E)?